# PDFBOX vertical text position with RotationMagic

Tags: pdfbox, text-extraction

I am using PDFBOX to extract the word coordinates. The PDF has some horizontal and vertical text mixed in a page, Here is the [PDF](https://1drv.ms/b/s!Avus1znFGI8Egt5yDSDHIIYvvarklg?e=vwTfYm), in Page 9, it has vertical text.

If I use PDFBOX `-RotationMagic` option, I can extract the vertical text layout correctly. However, its text Position is not correct inside `PDFTextStripper` class function:`WriteString()`.

How can I convert to original coordinates (e.g., origin is at top left).

In page 9, the "1.Introduction" is vertical text and after adding "-optionMagic", the coordinates inside `writeString()` is like this:

[image]

If I do not apply '-rotationMagic', the textPosition is like this. it splits "1:Introduciton" to multiple words. The first one is "1:"

[image]

How can I convert the first (rotated) coordinates to the second one. Why is the first one is (446.73, 1029.6)?

Comment: `-RotationMagic` is an option for the ExtractText command line tool, this isn't part of the API. It creates a modified temporary page for every angle. You could try to apply the rotation to your coordinates and see if that makes sense.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Thanks. I just add some details, could you help check how to do the conversion?

Comment: I don't have enough time right now; you need to use the "magic" rotation (probably 90 or 270) value and then create an AffineTransform from this by using getRotateInstance() (the parameter is radians, not degrees). Then apply this to the coordinates, by using `transform(Point2D, Point2D)`